# How to merge two Typescript ASTs

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api

i'm trying to merge two typescript AST's created from strings.

I create both with this method

```
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
    "file.ts",                  // filePath
    "function myFunction() {}", // fileText
    ts.ScriptTarget.Latest,     // scriptTarget
    true                        // setParentNodes -- sets the `parent` property
);
```

However, this will create node of type `ts.SourceFile`, and if i try to merge these two ASTs i get error when trying to print the final sourceFile: `"Unhandled SyntaxKind: SourceFile."`

How should i properly merge two ASTs?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is full working code example. When i run this it throws me directly into debugger (in browser) with aforementionde error.

I also tried to purposefully extract the `ArrowFunction` node (in ast2 it is wrapped in `SourceFile` and `ExpressionStatement`), then the program runs without error, but completely changes the inner template literal into invalid code.

```
const createAST = (str: string) =>
    ts.createSourceFile(
      "file.ts", // filePath
      str, // fileText
      ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, // scriptTarget
      true // setParentNodes -- sets the `parent` property
    )

  const template1 = `const arr = fields.map(() => {})`

  const template2 = `(field) => <Toolbar id={\`\${field.id}.\${field.name}\`} />`

  const ast1 = createAST(template1)
  const ast2 = createAST(template2)

  const replaceTransformer = <T extends ts.Node>(
    newNode: T
  ): ts.TransformerFactory<T> => {
    return context => {
      const visit: ts.Visitor = node => {
        if (ts.isArrowFunction(node)) return newNode

        return ts.visitEachChild(node, child => visit(child), context)
      }

      return node => ts.visitNode(node, visit)
    }
  }

  if (!ast1 || !ast2) return console.log("something went wrong")

  const result = ts.transform(ast1, [replaceTransformer(ast2)])

  const res = result.transformed[0]
  const printer = ts.createPrinter()
  const string = printer.printFile(res)
  console.log(string)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge these two ASTs"? Can you show the code for how the merging and printing is being done?

Comment: @DavidSherret i edited the question with reproducible example. Thanks for your contributions to open-source community, we love your work!

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my delay answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that the code has JSX in a `.ts` file (take a look at the result of `ast2`). To fix this, change the file name extension to `.tsx` so that it will parse as JSX.

The second issue is that putting a source file within a source file will lead to that error. Instead it's best to replace an expression with another expression so instead of providing the source file—`ast2`—provide `(ast2.statements[0] as ts.ExpressionStatement).expression`.

The third issue is that TypeScript is not designed to take the nodes from one source file and use them in another source file. For example, even with the fixes above, you will still get the following output:

```
const arr = fields.map((field) => <Toolbar id={) =field.idfield.name}/>);
```

...the reason for this is because the printer is using the positions from `ast2` to index into the source file text of `ast1`, so it spits out garbage. What I've recommended to do in the past is to set the `pos` and `end` of all the nodes in the expression from `ast2` to `-1` (the default used for factory created nodes). It’s a bit of a hacky workaround though.

**Full Example**

```
const createAST = (str: string) =>
  ts.createSourceFile(
    "file.tsx", // filePath
    str, // fileText
    ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, // scriptTarget
    true, // setParentNodes -- sets the `parent` property
  );

const template1 = `const arr = fields.map(() => {})`;
const template2 = "(field) => <Toolbar id={`${field.id}.${field.name}`} />";

const ast1 = createAST(template1);
const ast2 = createAST(template2);

const replaceTransformer = (
  newNode: ts.Node,
): ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> => {
  return (context) => {
    const visit: ts.Visitor = (node) => {
      if (ts.isArrowFunction(node)) {
        stripRanges(newNode);
        return newNode;
      }

      return ts.visitEachChild(node, (child) => visit(child), context);
    };

    return (node) => ts.visitNode(node, visit);
  };
};

const newNode = (ast2.statements[0] as ts.ExpressionStatement).expression;
stripRanges(newNode);
const result = ts.transform(ast1, [
  replaceTransformer(newNode),
]);

const res = result.transformed[0];
const printer = ts.createPrinter();
console.log(printer.printFile(res));

function stripRanges(node: ts.Node) {
  (node as any).pos = -1;
  (node as any).end = -1;

  ts.forEachChild(node, stripRanges);
}
```

Alternatively instead of stripping the ranges, just not setting the parent nodes also seems to work (providing `false` for that argument) as the printer doesn't seem to consult the source file text in that case… again, another hacky workaround given the current implementation of the printer.

Comment: Just curious: Isn't this a bug in Typescript API? Should I file an issue or is this work-as-intended scenario?

Comment: I wouldn’t really say it’s a bug because the ts compiler is not designed for this purpose, but no harm in asking them. It would probably degrade performance to improve it because it would have to travel up to the source file of every node instead of just holding onto the source file then using that with the descendant nodes. Or else they’d have to do a strict ast output which would break scenarios where people want comments in the output (though you could force this by stripping parents and ranges).